# Issue with adding conditions to secret santa app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on creating secret santa app for my christmas party.

For now it works, but I need to add some conditions.

```
function App() {
  var names = ["John", "Martha", "Adam", "Jane", "Michael"];

  const shuffle = (arr: string[]) => {
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
    }
    return arr;
  };

  const randomNames = shuffle(names);

  const matches = randomNames.map((name, index) => {
    return {
      santa: name,
      receiver: randomNames[index + 1] || randomNames[0],
    };
  });


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>Secret santa game</p>
        <select>
          <option>Select your name...</option>
          {names.map((name) => (
            <option> {name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <div>
          {matches.map((match) => {
            return (
              <div>
                {match.receiver},{match.santa}
                <br />
              </div>

            );
          })}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

John and Martha are couple so they will buy themselves presents outside of the party anyway, so if one of them is receiver and another is santa, I want to generate results again so they'll be assigned to someone else.

I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

Comment: How/Where do you define who is in a relationship with somebody else or is this just missing yet?

Comment: I don't have it yet

Comment: @Kasia, Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-18-playground-forked-ff5u8u . For now I consider the names are hard coded like John , Martha.

Comment: @Kasia was my answer helpful or do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your relationships like this:

```js
const couples = { John: "Martha" };
```

then have a function that verifies that your conditions are met:

```js
const conditions_check = (santa: string, receiver: string) => {
  if (couples[santa] === receiver) {
    return false;
  } else if (couples[receiver] === santa) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

and then finally you can check if your conditions are met while generating your matches and shuffle your pool of names again if needed:

```js
let matches = randomNames.map((name, index) => {
  let receiver = randomNames[(index + 1) % randomNames.length];
  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    if (conditions_check(name, receiver)) {
      break;
    }
    randomNames = shuffle(names);
  }
  return {
    santa: name,
    receiver: receiver
  };
});
```

You can check out the whole implementation in this [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-shtern-k272yg?file=/src/App.tsx).